# Gradle plugin for default properties

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am trying (and failing :) ) to create a gradle plugin that has a default set of versions for dependencies and can be overridden in the gradle.build file that is calling my plugin. Ideally something like the sudo-code below

MyDefaultPropertiesPlugin.groovy

```
project.versions.springBoot="1.0.0-RELEASE"
```

MyPlugin.groovy

```
project.apply plugin: MyDefaultPropertiesPlugin
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${project.versions.springBoot}")
```

build.gradle

```
versions.springBoot = "1.1.0-RELEASE"
project.apply plugin "my.plugin"
```

I attempted to do using extensions but ran into isssue's via the ordering when overriding. (versions doesnt exist)
I would greatly appreciate any advise on this, maven would be easy, but my gradle knowledge is still evolving :)

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

Plugins have to defer accessing the build model until after build scripts have been evaluated. Easiest solution is to use `project.afterEvaluate {}`, but there are others. For more information, see answers to similar questions here or on http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I came up with the above solution as the simplest method i could see, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a pretty workable if not perfect solution, I will update if i think of anything better, my gradle is at a learning level, so please commend if this can be improved.
This allows me to define a set of versions and clients to overwrite those versions with a simple property

MyDefaultVersionsPlugin.groovy

```
class MyDefaultVersionsPlugin implements Plugin<Project>{
    project.extensions.create('versions', MyVersions, project)
}

class MyVersions{
    String spring
    String slf4j
    public MyVersions (Project project){
         spring = setVersion(project,'springVersion', 'x.x.x.x')
         slf4j = setVersion(project,'slf4jVersion', 'x.x.x.x')
    }

    private static String setVersion(Project project, String name, String version){
         if(project.hasProperties(name)){
             return project.getProperties().get(name)
         }
         else {
             return version
         }
    }
}
```

MyPlugin.groovy

```
project.apply plugin: MyDefaultVersionsPlugin
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${project.versions.spring}")
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript { ext { springVersion = 'x.x.x.x'} }
```